# Ant design Area chart - remove canvas margins

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

Im trying to set Ant Desing Area chart to not have margin/padding on the sides so my chart will perfectly fit inside the wrapping container - but for some reason i couldn't find the attribute for that on Ant's documentation.
Also i would like the Chart to start from 0 on the Y axis
i tried the "beginAtZero" attribute but also didnt worked

**these are my configurations:**

```js
const config = {
    height: 60,
    data: volumeData,
    autoFit: true,
    xField: "date",
    yField: "count",
    padding: [5],
    xAxis: false,
    yAxis: false,
    color: "#916afc",
    legend: false,
    point: {
      shape: 'circle'
    },
  };
```

**wrpper container css**

```css
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px rgb(0 0 0 / 5%);
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
```

**and the chart:**

```
<Area {...config} />
```

[image]

Comment: Hi did you resolve the canvas padding issue?

Answer (score 2):

You should set the scale.min of y field to `0`.

```
{ 
  /* ... */
  meta: {
    count: { min: 0 }
  }
}
```

Then the y axis will start wiht zero.

Comment: thank you :)

do you how can i solve the canvas padding issue also ?

Comment: and the x Field ? how to make it begin from zero

Answer (score 2):

To remove the side padding/margin, explicitly set the xField's range to the default of [0, 1]. To change the starting yAxis value, set the yField's min to 0 (as proposed by [@atool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69074278/14250695)).

```
const config = {
    /* ... */
    xField: "date",
    yField: "count",
    /* ... */
    meta: {
        "date": {
            range: [0, 1]
        },
        "count": {
            min: 0
        }
    }
  };
```